# Publishing Queue can not be sort on the Time filter

Tags: 2011, cme

I am using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR 1 and If i try to sort the entries in my Publishing queue on the basis of **Time** filter it does not work .i.e it does not put any effect on the publishing queue list. See the screen shot below:

[image]

Comment: Just confirming that I can recreate this behavior on 2011 SP1, but the sorting-by-time functionality behaves as expected on 2013.

Comment: Please see my answer, it is a known issue with 2011

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out while looking for some other issue.

This is a known issue with SDL Tridion SP1 HR 1 and following hotfix - CM_2011.1.1.82194 available at SDL Tridion World at below location:

https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2011_SP1_1/index.aspx

need to be apply to fix this issue.